# Lex program doesn't do anything

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

I am trying to write a program using Lex which recognizes some letters, numbers and do minor things. The problem is that the program does not recognizes anything. In fact, I changed the rules to a simple rule to recognizes everything, but still does nothing. What's happening? Maybe it's simple (it must be, there are few lines), but I am new with Lex and I am not able to fix it. Thanks

simple.l:

```
%{
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <ctype.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int count = 0;


%}


/*Reglas*/
%%
[a-zA-Z_]*[a-zA-Z_0-9]*      { count++; printf("%s ", yytext); }
.*                           { count++; printf("%s ", yytext); }

%%
/*Procedimientos de usuario*/

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  FILE * yyin;
  if(argc == 2) {
    yyin =fopen(argv[1],"rt");
    if(yyin == NULL) {
      printf("File %s can not be opened\n", argv[1]);
      exit(-1);
    }
  } else {
    printf("Error in arguments");
    exit(-1);
  }


  yylex();
  printf("Counter : %d \n", count);


  fclose(yyin);
  return 0;

}
```

Imput file: example.txt

```
CSC104H1
CSC108H1
CSC204H1
CSC258H1
```

Also, I need to use ctrl+d to finish the program(as I saw in stackoverflow), if not, the program does not finish by itself.

Comment: When you say it does nothing, does that mean there's no output other than the counter being 0? Or that nothing is printed at all including the counter? How are you running the program?

Comment: The counter is printed, but counter value is 0. Another problem is that I need to use ctrl+d to finish the program and see the output. If not, lex does not finish. I compile and run using: lex simple.l;  gcc lex.yy.c -o prog -ll; ./prog example.txt

Comment: You'll also want to take a careful look at your patterns. In particular, `.*` will match an entire line, which will be a longer match than your first pattern, so the first pattern will only trigger when the identifier is the only thing on the line. Also, no pattern matches a newline. And your identifier pattern is also a bit odd, because you make the leading alphabetic character optional (with the `*`), which means that it's equivalent to a simple `[[:alnum:]]*`.

Comment: I will take your advice to create my patterns, because the real patterns I need to write are not that patterns, are more complex. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  FILE * yyin;
  // ...
  yyin = ....
}
```

Here, `yyin` is a *local variable*. The scanner is using the global variable with the same name, which this declaration is shadowing.

Delete the declaration and it will work fine.

Your first clue is that the scanner is evidently reading from standard input, not from the file you specified, which is why it waits for you to type an end-of-file indicator.